# How to select from an expression in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm really new to SQL and quite struggling with this. I have 2 tables

- MATERIAL (CODE, NAME, BUYPRICE)
- BILL (CODE, DETAIL, AMOUNT)

I want to return a new temporary column `TOTALMONEYTOPAID` which is `BUYPRICE * AMOUNT`.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    TOTALMONEYTOPAID 
FROM
    MATERIAL, BILL 
WHERE
    TOTALMONEYTOPAID = BUYPRICE * AMOUNT
```

This obviously doesn't work.

I searched around for something like `declare @variable` but I don't know how to use it. Many thanks with your answer.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a really simple query:

```
select Material.Code, Name, Detail, BuyPrice*Amount as TotalMoneyPaid
from Material
join Bill on Bill.Code=Material.Code
```